# jQuery: Can't find a tag under only the current class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this:

HTML:

```
<p class="Link"><a href="...">Test1</a></p>
<p class="Link"><a href="...">Test2</a></p>
<p class="Link"><a href="...">Test3</a></p>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Link').hover(function() {
        $('.Link a').css('color', 'black');
    }, function() {
        $('.Link a').css('color', 'white');
    });
});
```

First of all, I need to change the anchor color when the mouse hovers over the paragraph, not just the anchor.  Secondly, I need to do this without creating a unique id for each paragraph or anchor.  With the code as it is, it changes the color for all three anchors tags.  I only want it to change the color on the anchor contained within the paragraph I am currently hovering over.  Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` which refers to the specific element that received the event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Link').hover(function() {
             // Get the <a> element from within the context of
             //    the element that received the event, represented
             //    by "this" 
        $('a',this).css('color', 'black');
    }, function() {
        $('a',this).css('color', 'white');
    });
});
```

Doing:

```
$('a',this).css('color', 'black');
```

is *effectively* the same as doing:

```
$(this).find('a').css('color', 'black');
```

- http://api.jquery.com/find/

Of course, you could always accomplish this using purely CSS.

---

**EDIT:**

If all you're doing is changing some CSS attributes, you don't really need javascript.

To use a purely CSS approach, do this:

```
.Link a {
    color: black;
}

.Link a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

Because you're doing this on an `<a>` element, it is supported on IE6. Starting with IE7 (and most other browsers) you can use the same technique on other elements too.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your last statement?

Comment: @Albion - If you're only changing a CSS attribute, then the `:hover` pseudo selector accomplishes the same thing. If you can accomplish what you need without javascript, then that is best. I'll update my answer at the bottom with an example.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't set margins on an anchor tag so I had to surround it with a paragraph to create the 3D button press effect I was going for.  Since I change the margins in the paragraph and the color/text-decoration in the anchor on hover, and the paragraph is wider then the anchor, my margins change a split second before the color.  It was weird on the eyes.  So I added the jQuery to change the margins, color and text-decoration when the mouse is over either then <p> or the <a>.  You can see the effect at http://test.stanektool.com above the three product images.

Comment: Ok, now I feel stupid.  It seems that my color change was wrong.  To create the right look I don't want to change the color when the button is depressed.  You were right patrick, I can do the entire thing with CSS.  But, thanks for the lesson in "this".  It taught me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).find("a").css("color", "black");
```

should do the trick.

The problem is, that ".Link a" matches ALL anchors that are in a paragraph. You probably should read into CSS again with that kind of misunderstanding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the selector $(this) inside the event to quickly refer to the element which is hovered over. After that you can use .find() to find any elements inside it.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.Link').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'black');
        $(this).find("a").css('color', 'black');

    }, function() {
        $(this).css('color', 'white');
        $(this).find("a").css('color', 'white');
    });
});
```